# Ubuntu on 2 different disks

Tags: partitioning, disk, boot-partition

I'm trying to setup a Linux server, I did this configuration:

[image]

The purpose of this server is the following: I will install VirtualBox on it in order to run about 10 VMs. This is why I gave 350 GB to /home.
I might get some logs so I set up 40GB to /var.
The logs will be created by softwares I will put in /opt.

Otherwise, I don't really know which size to put for /usr. Moreover, should I add a /boot on the second disk (sdb)?

Is this OK to separate the partitions on 2 differents disks like that? The system will boot?

Thank you,

Comment: looks fine for me because you did not define /boot its good because /boot will come under second disk you can proceed with installation

Comment: Please provide what the intention is to do with the server (by adding it into the question). The hard disk layout for the partitions is fine, the sizes of the partitions are not good in my eyes. Biggest issue: /home/ 350G. That smells like a DESKTOP not a server.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of informations. I Just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this OK to separate the partitions on 2 differents disks like that?

Yes, but I would not do this.

It is possible to prepare for a failure of a disk. If you have it like this and either of the disks dies you can not boot. It might be better to install the system on the 2nd disk and then edit the configuration of the server software to use a "data" partition with a size of 500Gb on disk 1. Apache, MySQL, Cups can all be told to use another location than `/var/`. That would make your backup plan easier: backup this one "data" disk makes sure you have it all safe. If the disk with data dies you take it out, put in a new one and restore your backup.

This data disk basically holds all you own data. MySQL database, website, VBox containers and everything else. If the disk fills up you buy a 2Tb disk, install it next to the 500Gb, move it over to the 2Tb and take the 500Gb out. Easy and quick.

If the system disk dies you make a new system disk and restore the settings files for each server software (and you of course have backups on the "data" disk of those configuration files.

Nowadays I would set a server up like this:

```
SCSI5 (2,0,0)
/data {remaining space}
/data/configuration/ {1Gb or so}

SCSI5 (2,1,0)
/ {remaining space}
/tmpfs {15Gb}
swap  {35Gb}
```

And change the config files to have it use /data/

Have a look at how a GCE (Google Compute Engine) works: you get a base system and mount your own user disk into it. And that user disk holds all your own software and data.

Regarding this specific setup:

> I'm trying to setup a Linux server

There are several servers you can set up: web, database, printer, file and tons more. The partition scheme should reflect what kind of server you are going to use.

For a SERVER 350Gb for /home/ is far too large. /home/ should have hardly anything in it and you can suffice with a mere 25Gb.

If this is a webserver (Apache) and database server (MySQL) will by default store its data in `/var/`. Depending on usage that directory can grow quickly and 30Gb might be too little. Well to me it is if you have 350Gb wasted on home.

Same goes for a print server: CUPS will use `/var/` to store all of the history of all the prints (when set up to save those).

64Gb for `/opt/` can be enough. It depends on what you are going to use. Eclipse, Tomcat, Jasperserver (a server that can create templates to create a pdf from mysql) can have it fill up quickly too.

Both `/var/` and `/opt/` would be better of getting each 150Gb from `/home/`.

The 111Gb for root is a lot too since the 2 big ones (`/var/` and `/opt`) have their own partitions. But I guess to fill up the disk it is good enough. You could make it smaller and have `/home/` on that one too.

15 Gb for `/tmp/`? What are you expecting to do with 15Gb of space there?

Comment: I put 350GB because I'm going to create a lot of  VMs on it.

Comment: You should put those in /opt/ as a 3rd party. Or see the edit: put them on disk1 in /data/ ;)

Comment: If I do like you wrote with /data on disk1, the installer will put /opt, /var on the second disk, right? I don't think there will be enough space

Comment: Yes. But you wont be using opt except for installing the 3rd party software. You put the vBox containers on /data/. Same with /var/: you tell mysql, apache. cups to use "/data/var/../". Like I said in the answer: make disk2 a system disk you can always boot from even if disk1 dies.